# How do I do String comparison in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I am using the following code to compare strings but it always takes me to the `else`. Why?

```
print("Enter your state abbreviation: ")
state_abbreviation = gets
if state_abbreviation.upcase == "NC"
  puts("North Carolina")
elsif state_abbreviation.upcase == "SC"
  puts("Sourth Carolina")
elsif state_abbreviation.upcase == "GA"
  puts("Georgia")
elsif state_abbreviation.upcase == "FL"
  puts("Florida")
elsif state_abbreviation.upcase == "AL"
  puts("Alabama")
else
  puts("You have enter wrong abbreviation")
end
```

I also have tried `.eql?("string")` but I get the same result.

Comment: I really don't know Ruby very well, but why have this difficult and fragile if-if-if-else structure?  Use a HashMap and, if you get nothing back, set the error message.

This would also help the newline problem everyone stepped out below.

Comment: 1. I am very new to ruby so even dont know if HashMP exit there?

2. I dont like case-when!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The string returned by gets will have a linebreak at the end. Use `String#chomp` to remove it (i.e. `state_abbreviation = gets.chomp`).

PS: Your code would look much cleaner (IMHO) if you used case-when instead of if-elsif-elsif.

Comment: +1 for the `case` suggestion. 100% agree!

Comment: chomp thing had driven me crazy....thanks for the answer..You are the real MVP.

Answer (score 16):

I don't have enough points to comment, but I think the hash idea by Chris Jester-Young is really neat.

```
statehash = { "RI" => "Rhode Island", "NC" => "North Carolina" }

print "Enter your state abbreviation: "
state_abbreviation = gets.chomp.upcase

puts statehash[state_abbreviation]
```

this code is a lot more concise and clear than a bunch of elsif and shorter than a case.  It also allows for a hash of state objects, where the key is the abbreviation and the value is the object.

Comment: Thanks for the vote of confidence! Much appreciated.

Comment: I would actually use an array, with an `in_array?(state)` or something of the sort. Unless hash has its own syntax like that.

Comment: statehash[state_abbreviation] either returns a value so in my example RI or NC work, else nil is returned.  Hashes do have .has_key?, .has_value? but I don't see the need to use that here.

Answer (score 5):

Before the big block, say:

```
state_abbreviation.chomp!
```

As an alternative to sepp2k's excellent suggestion to use `case`, consider making a hash with the state abbreviations as keys.

Answer (score 0):

`gets` returns what you typed with a newline.  Try `state_abbreviation = gets.chomp`

Answer (score 0):

You are using gets, and probably your shell/input is adding a newline (\n) character at the end of the string, and maybe you may want to use the case statement:

example:

```
print("Enter your state abbreviation: ") 
state_abbreviation = gets.strip

case state_abbreviation
  when "NC" then puts("North Carolina")
  when "SC" then puts("South Carolina")
  # ...
  else puts("You have enter wrong abbreviation")
end
```

Answer (score 0):

While we're off topic and commenting on the approach vs. the problem, check out this rails cast.  He pulls in all the state abbreviations from a website.  I'm a fan of this because it gets the mappings out of your code entirely (though might be a good idea to save the site, just in case).  You could then put that together with a cache to prevent actually hitting the DB.

http://railscasts.com/episodes/179-seed-data

http://railscasts.com/episodes/115-caching-in-rails-2-1

Comment: It's not a good idea to build in a dependency on another site unless you own it. Your code can break if the site goes down, or go to a crawl if theirs is slow. Also, if your code is hit a lot it will hit their site a lot, potentially costing them money, without them benefitting. It's similar to deep-linking, which is a good way to get your site's IP added to their .htaccess file denying you access. If the data is unique to that site then arrange for usage rights as it could be copyrighted. If it's not copyrighted then build your own local repository where you control its availability.