# Ruby, '==' not working

Tags: ruby, exit

Here is my code:

```
@cmd == "exit"
```

when @cmd is a string variable "exit" it doesn't return true. Any suggestions why?

-Edit-

-Resolved

Error: Because @cmd was made by using '@cmd = gets' it added '\n' to @cmd. Thanks for your help!

Comment: `@cmd` would not be `"exit"` in that case.

Comment: Chomp chomp chomp maybe? [(How do I do String comparison in Ruby?)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2016169/how-do-i-do-string-comparison-in-ruby).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@cmd *must* contain something other than exit.  Is it possible that @cmd contains some kind of whitespace character like a newline or space?  Perhaps try:

```
@cmd.chomp!
@cmd.strip!
@cmd == "exit"
```

If @cmd is being set from $stdin.readline, then it will likely have the newline character in it.  Stripping and chomping will help eliminate uncertainty.

Comment: @learningcoder Looks like you're new here, so I'd like to point out that it's polite, if someone answers your question, to click the check mark to the left of the question (under the score) to indicate that this answer answers your question.

Answer (score 1):

see what exactly `@cmd` is:

```
p @cmd
```

or try:

```
@cmd.to_s == "exit"
```

Comment: :O thanks i just realized "@cmd" had \n at the end. I used gets to get "@cmd" and its adding \n to the end. Any idea on how to remove the \n.

Comment: @learningcoder See Kyle Burton's answer. `@cmd.chomp!` should strip off the trailing whitespace.

Comment: oh yes, there is an answer covering this much better, see @Kyle's answer